# Control selection order from a sequence

Tags: xquery

How do I control the order of selection from a `for $x in (...)` ? In the last line of XQuery below, I want the result to be in the order `$retmax`, `$retmin`, but it comes out in reverse order.

```
<result>
{
    let $max := max(doc("countries.xml")//country/(@population div @area))
    let $min := min(doc("countries.xml")//country/(@population div @area))
    for $country in doc("countries.xml")//country
    let $density := $country/(@population div @area)
    let $ret_min := if ($density = $min)
                    then <lowest density="{$density}">{data($country/@name)}</lowest>
                    else ()
    let $ret_max := if ($density = $max) 
                    then <highest density="{$density}">{data($country/@name)}</highest>
                    else ()
    for $r in ($ret_max, $ret_min) return $r
}   
</result>
```

produces:

```
  <result>
    <lowest density="0.026752619966905682">Greenland</lowest>
    <highest density="31052.3125">Macau</highest>
  </result>
```

but I want:

```
  <result>
    <highest density="31052.3125">Macau</highest>
    <lowest density="0.026752619966905682">Greenland</lowest>
  </result>
```

Comment: Such complex code is bound to have a logical error -- it isn't in `for $r in ($ret_max, $ret_min) return $r` , which by the way is unnatural way to write just `($ret_max, $ret_min)` -- the issue is in the complicated surrounding expression. Therefore the question is titled inappropriately -- a better title would be: "Please, find the fault in my logic" -- and this doesn't qualify as too XQuery-related question.

Comment: I tried to `return ($ret_max, $ret_min)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Rose Perrone, try this query: `for $r in (7, 2) return $r` The result is `7 2`. Try the same, but with `7` and `2` replaced by values that are nodes -- again the result is the nodes in the order they appear in the expression. This isn't surprizing, it follows from the definition of sequence in the Xpath Data Model. What this means is that the in the provided in your question expression, there is some issue with the logic of the sub-expression that is surrounding `for $r in ($ret_max, $ret_min)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it...

```
let $ordered_countries := for $country in doc("countries.xml")//country
                          let $density := $country/(@population div @area)
                          order by $density 
                          return $country
let $low  := $ordered_countries[1]
let $high := $ordered_countries[fn:last()]
return (
    <lowest density="{$low/(@population div @area)}">{data($low/@name)}</lowest>,
    <highest density="{$high/(@population div @area)}">{data($high/@name)}</highest>
)
```